# Debian ограничение команд

Tags: debian

Как запретить пользователю www-data выполнение команд? К примеру запретить выполнение всех команд кроме нескольких.

Comment: [selinux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux), [apparmor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) и [т.д. и т.п.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Избирательное_управление_доступом)

Comment: Вы повторяете себя. www-data -- стстемный пользователь без возможности логина